# How to lunch App-Store with in my iPhone application with list of application of any particular company?

Tags: iphone, app-store

```
NSString *str = @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/in/artist/quizmine-com/id356028414?uo=4";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString:str]];
```

Above code is working fine in my iPad application but it is not working in my iPhone application why? Can some one help me?

After lunch iTunes Store it through's some message "Your request is not complete".